# In spring-graphql, how to auto-generate schema from annotations (e.g. @QueryMapping) without defining `.graphql` files?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, graphql

I have a project, written in Kotlin/Java that uses `spring-graphql` annotation like `@QueryMapping`, `@MutationMapping`, etc.

The whole schema is defined in code using the above annotations.

But, in all the tutorials I've found, a `.graphql` file is needed, which is a **huge duplication** and a burden - especially if the schema is a bit complicated.

If I don't specify the `.graphql` file, the playground/graphiql doesn't load.

**How to auto-generate the schema from code to be used by graphiql/playground without writing `.graphql` files?** Thanks

Example tutorials:

1. [techdozo](https://github.com/techdozo/graphql-spring-annotation)
2. [eh3rrera](https://github.com/eh3rrera/graphql-java-spring-boot-example)

Answer (score 3):

Spring for GraphQL has a ["schema-first"](https://spring.io/blog/2021/07/06/introducing-spring-graphql#schema-first-vs-object-first) approach, that means you have to declare the schema yourself (common approach is to use SDL in `.graphls` files). Spring for GraphQL cannot generate the schema from annotations.

If you want to use "code-first" approach, where you write code with annotations and then let the tool generate the schema, you could try [MicroProfile GraphQL](https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-graphql-1.0/microprofile-graphql.html#microprofile_graphql), but I'm not sure, if that works in Spring.

Comment: Is there a way to generate the code from the schema in spring-graphql and somehow plug the implementation to it?

Comment: DGS framework does code generation from schema

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but [this repo](https://github.com/Fradantim/spring-graphql-2-jpa) has an example on schema auto-generation based on `@QueryMapping` annotated methods and `@Argument` annotated parameters.

This is done with reflection on application startup.
`@MutationMapping` is not present in the example, but could be added by reading carefully [GraphQLConfig.java](https://github.com/Fradantim/spring-graphql-2-jpa/blob/main/src/main/java/com/fradantim/graphql2jpa/config/GraphQLConfig.java)

Comment: What tool does the code generation?

Comment: No tools, lots of reflection plus the models and builders provided by `spring-boot-starter-graphql`.